# How to converta string into date in the format of yyyy-MM-dd and store it in database?

Tags: java

This is the code that I have done but the date is not getting stored in the same format as the manufacturing date in the database (yyyy-MM-dd)

This calculates the expiry date for the Item:

```
   public   void calculateExpiryDate(List<Item> items)//to calculate expiry date
   {
     System.out.println("Calculate expiry");

     try
     {// to get the data one by one and calculate its expiry date
       for(Item ob : items)
       {
       Item i1 = (Item)ob;
       Date dd = (Date)i1.getManufacturingDate();
       int  m = i1.getUseBeforeMonths();
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       String date = sdf.format(dd);
       String d[] = date.split("-");
       d[1]=String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(d[1])+m);
       // loop to calculate expiry date
       while(Integer.parseInt(d[1])>12)
       {
            d[1] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(d[1])-12);
            d[0] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(d[0])+1);
       }
       String d1 =d[0]+"-"+d[1]+"-"+d[2];
    
       
       Date dt = (Date)sdf.parse(d1);//converting string into date
       i1.setExpiryDate(dt);//setting the expiry date into the database
       System.out.println(i1.getExpiryDate());
       }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }

     
     
   }
```

Comment: the casts your performing are redundant

Comment: A `Date` doesn't have a format... but currently you're formatting and parsing with the wrong pattern. `m` means minutes; `M` means month... It's not really clear what you're trying to do here, but I'd *strongly* recommend against all this string parsing and formatting in order to perform calendrical calculations. If you're using Java 8, use java.time. If you're using Java 7, use Joda Time. If you *have* to use Date and Calendar, at least do the arithmetic using those types instead of all this text manipulation.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of how you are trying to get the expiry date given the initial date?  Is it a x number of days after the initial date?

Comment: manufacturing date is given and months before use is  provided in the database. So for every item the expiry date is to be calculated. So i extracted the manufacturing date and the months before use. I converted the date into string and then split it and then add the months with the months before use and if that value is greater than 12 then subtract 12 from months and increase year by 1. I got the expiry date correct but the issue is i have to store the expiry date in the database in the same format as manufacturing date(yyyy-MM-dd) but i am unable to

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` does not have a format, since it is a time measured since 1970. If we are speaking about format, then we speak about how date is displayed, which is a different issue. Naturally, you need to change the format of `"yyyy-mm-dd"` to `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, but, again: 1st July 2015 is the same date as 2015-07-01. The difference is being on the way it is displayed. Needless to say, a huge part of your code is not needed. You just need to create a date from the String, do whatever you need to do and then display the date in your preferred format.

Comment: actually i have to calculate the expiry date of items with the given manufacturing date and the months before use given. So i calculated the expiry date i have to store the expiry date in the same format as manufacturing date(yyyy-mm-dd). So how to do that????

Comment: @Neha, your approach is not without merits, but it is pointless to convert dates to strings, then to numbers, then back to strings and then back to dates. You can imagine that with so many conversion your function will not perform well, especially if this function is a frequent operation of a complex algorithm. You can use Calendar to aid you, like in this example: http://www.coderanch.com/t/411814/java/java/Incrementing-Date-Months Note, that you will need to use your dates instead of current.